# INPUT TYPE RADIO PROBLEMAS CON ID PHP Y JVSCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo por cada label dos input type radio para si y otro para no.
el problema es que lo tengo con los mismos id, pero al cambiar los id, no me toma el formulario y no me manda la validacion que hago. como podria trabajar con esos input type radio con los id, para agruparlos, tipo un select. que al escoger uno, me de el valor del value.

```
        <script>

      $(function(){
         $('#enviar').on('click', function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
          var elemento = document.getElementById("serie").value
             if (elemento == ""){
              alert("Debes llenar el campo serie.")
              return false}
              var elemento = 
           document.getElementById("identificacion").value
         if (elemento == ""){
         alert("Debes llenar el campo identificacion.")
         return false}

    var id_recolector = '<?= $_SESSION['id_recolector']; ?>';
    var serie = $('#serie').val();
    var identificacion = $('#identificacion').val();
    var id_orden = $('#id_orden').val();
    var estado = $('#estado').val();
    var horario_rec = $('#horario_rec').val();
    var cable_hdmi = $('#cable_hdmi').val();
    var cable_av = $('#cable_av').val();
    var fuente = $('#fuente').val();
    var control_1 = $('#control_1').val();
    var adicional = $('#adicional').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "./javascriptvalidacion/insertar.php",
        data: {'id_recolector': id_recolector, 
            'serie':serie, 
            'identificacion':identificacion,
               'id_orden':id_orden,
               'estado':estado,
               'horario_rec':horario_rec,
               'cable_hdmi':cable_hdmi,
               'cable_av':cable_av,
               'fuente':fuente,
               'control_1':control_1,
               'adicional':adicional},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#imagen').show();
                $('#mensajes').html('Procesando datos...');

            },
            success:function(respuesta){
                $('#imagen').hide();
                if(respuesta==1){
                    $('#mensajes').html('<div class="alert alert-info">Enviado correctamente');
                }
                else{
                    $('#mensajes').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Verificar Identificación Cliente');
                  }
            }    
        })
     })
 })
```

```
<div id="addProductModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="" method="POST" name="add_product" id="add_product">
                <div class="modal-header">                      
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Equipo</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label><strong>Cable HDMI</strong></label>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="cable_hdmi" name="cable_hdmi" value="Si" checked>Si
                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="cable_hdmi" name="cable_hdmi" value="No">No
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><strong>Cable AV</strong></label>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="cable_av" name="cable_av" value="Si" checked>Si
                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="cable_av" name="cable_av" value="No">No
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><strong>Fuente</strong></label>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="fuente" name="fuente" value="Si" checked>Si
                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="fuente" name="fuente" value="No">No
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><strong>Control</strong></label>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="control_1" name="control_1" value="Si" checked>Si
                        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="control_1" name="control_1" value="No">No
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label><strong>Estado</strong></label>
                        <select type="text" name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="A-CONFIRMAR">A CONFIRMAR</option>
                      </select>                 
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><strong>Serie</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" name="serie"  id="serie" class="form-control" required>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><strong>Identificacion CTE</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" name="identificacion" id="identificacion" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><strong>Sugerencias/Opcional</strong></label>
                        <textarea type="text" name="adicional" id="adicional" class="form-control">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><strong>Nro Orden</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" name="id_orden"  id="id_orden" class="form-control"  value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['id_order']))
                         { echo $_SESSION['id_order']; } ?>" required>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="horario_rec" id="horario_rec" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'); echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");?>" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><strong>ID Recolector</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" name="id_recolector"  id="id_recolector" class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['logged_user']))
                        { echo $_SESSION['id_recolector']; } ?>" required>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
                    <input type="submit" id="enviar" class="btn btn-success" value="Guardar datos">
                    <div id="alert"><img id="imagen" src="img/cargando.gif" alt=""><span id="mensajes"></span></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y aqui hago la validacion, trate de cambiar los id, pero no me hace la validacion que quiero supongo porque no sabe que id elegir y no se ejecuta la condicion, estuve leyendo que se puede agrupar los input type radio para trabarjlos de otra manera, yo los estaba trabajando con input type select pero necesito ahora pasarlos a type radio porque da una mejor interface aca a continuacion les dejo el codigo donde hago la validacion para insertar el formulario del modal, mi prgunta es, si tengo este problema, quiere decir que tendria que tambien cambiar los name de cada input type radio, y si es asi tuviera que agregarlos en el php para insertarlos, pero tuviera entonces que crear condiciones para que ingrese si o no si se clickea cierto input. o me equivoco y es solo arreglar el formulario con id

```
     <?php

     require_once ("../conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que 
       conecta a la base de datos
    // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be 
    (html/javascript-) code

    sleep(2);

    $id_orden = $_POST['id_orden'];
    $serie =$_POST['serie'];
    $identificacion = $_POST['identificacion'];
    $cable_hdmi =$_POST['cable_hdmi'];
     $cable_av = $_POST['cable_av'];
     $fuente= $_POST['fuente'];
      $control_1=$_POST['control_1'];
       $estado=$_POST['estado'];
       $horario_rec=$_POST['horario_rec'];
        $adicional=$_POST['adicional'];
        $id_recolector =$_POST['id_recolector'];

        $sql1="SELECT identificacion
        FROM express WHERE 
        identificacion='$identificacion'";
         $resultado = $con->query($sql1);
        $fila = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

          if($fila==0){

          echo 0;

       }
         else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO autorizar (id_recolector_2, 
      id_orden, serie, identificacion, cable_hdmi, cable_av, 
       fuente,control_1,estado_rec,horario_rec,
       adicional) VALUES 

      ('$id_recolector','$id_orden','$serie',
      '$identificacion','$cable_hdmi',
         '$cable_av','$fuente',
        '$control_1','$estado','$horario_rec','$adicional')";
          $insert = $con->query($sql) or die (mysqli_erno());
             echo 1;
             }


             ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo resolvi recibiendo los input de esos id que estaban repetidos

```
 <script>

        $(function(){
           $('#enviar').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
      var elemento = document.getElementById("serie").value
         if (elemento == ""){
          alert("Debes llenar el campo serie.")
          return false}
          var elemento = 
       document.getElementById("identificacion").value
     if (elemento == ""){
     alert("Debes llenar el campo identificacion.")
     return false}

var id_recolector = '<?= $_SESSION['id_recolector']; ?>';
var serie = $('#serie').val();
var identificacion = $('#identificacion').val();
var id_orden = $('#id_orden').val();
var estado = $('#estado').val();
var horario_rec = $('#horario_rec').val();
var cable_hdmi = document.forms["add_product"]["cable_hdmi"].value;
    var cable_av= document.forms["add_product"]["cable_av"].value;
    var fuente = document.forms["add_product"]["fuente"].value;
    var control_1= document.forms["add_product"]["control_1"].value;
var adicional = $('#adicional').val();

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "./javascriptvalidacion/insertar.php",
    data: {'id_recolector': id_recolector, 
        'serie':serie, 
        'identificacion':identificacion,
           'id_orden':id_orden,
           'estado':estado,
           'horario_rec':horario_rec,
           'cable_hdmi':cable_hdmi,
           'cable_av':cable_av,
           'fuente':fuente,
           'control_1':control_1,
           'adicional':adicional},
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#imagen').show();
            $('#mensajes').html('Procesando datos...');

        },
        success:function(respuesta){
            $('#imagen').hide();
            if(respuesta==1){
                $('#mensajes').html('<div class="alert alert-info">Enviado correctamente');
            }
            else{
                $('#mensajes').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Verificar Identificación Cliente');
              }
        }    
    })
   })
 })
```

y al formulario le quite los id de los que repetia con el radio button